# Resolution and accuracy of google maps elevation service

Tags: google-maps, gis, elevation, google-elevation-api

Does anybody know details about the resolution and accuracy of the google maps elevation service (Sep. 2019)?
I couldn't find it in the google developer guide. Just guesswork in some chats.
Does google elevation service refer to the surface model (DSM, incl. natural and built features) or the elevation model (DEM, bare-earth)? 
I know, "elevation service" implies the DEM but maybe it's just the (marketing) name...

Answer (score 0):

I think they use SRTM1 data. That means the resolution is 30m. In some countries are high res data for free available, e.g. here:

https://www.opengeodata.nrw.de/produkte/geobasis/dom/dom1l/